# Red Alert 3: Source file not found

Tags: wine, games

I'm trying to install RA3 using Wine 3.0. Right after agreeing to T&Cs when it starts installing it gives me the following error: "Source file not found: Command and Conquer (tm) Red Alert (tm) 3. Verify that the file exists and that you can access it."

I've installed three other C&C games without any problems. For verification, please note the following:

1. Original game with serial number
2. Has worked on Play-on-Linux
3. PoL, however, crashes after each system update.
4. Wine 3.0 installs all other games.

I've trying to locate the file directory where the missing source file could be located but cannot find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It has happened to me a few times that game CD/DVD's do not read properly with wine.
And it happened with RA3 too. I think it is a `wine` problem because Linux reads the CD/DVD ok? But the game does not?

A CD/DVD reading error in either `wine` or Linux can stop this game from 
installing, with errors about missing files etc.?

Use a DVD copy if you have one, or copy the whole DVD to a temp folder.
Pull up a terminal, and it goes something like this:

```
mkdir ~/Temp/RA3
```

`cd /media/$USER/RA3`    (or wherever your DVD is mounted)

```
cp -r * ~/Temp/RA3
```

And it may take a while so have a cuppa or something. Just make sure that all files have been copied by comparing the size/s. 
And then run AutoRun.exe from there.
Worked for me in wine v3.0.2.

Comment: I've copied the disk to Documents (not sure if it will affect the outcome). Unfortunately AutoRun.exe won't run. It just exits. But I'll ty again using other methods.